# Error: `#elif with no expression` - happens only on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw

I'm trying to compile a project using a library I made on Windows, using MinGW 4.8.1 x86. The project compiles fine on Linux.

*Common.hpp* is included before everything else, and defines some macros depending on the current OS. Then *ConsoleFmt.hpp* is included, and it includes a file depending on the previously defined macros.

I'm getting an error, however - here's the code and the error message:

---

**Common.hpp**

```
#if (__linux || __unix || __posix)
    #define SSVU_OS_LINUX
#elif (_WIN64 || _WIN32)
    #define SSVU_OS_WINDOWS
#else
    #define SSVU_OS_UNKNOWN
#endif
```

---

**ConsoleFmt.hpp**

```
#include "Common.hpp"

#ifdef SSVU_OS_LINUX
    #include "SSVUtils/Core/ConsoleFmt/Internal/ConsoleFmtImplUnix.hpp"
#elif SSVU_OS_WINDOWS
    #include "SSVUtils/Core/ConsoleFmt/Internal/ConsoleFmtImplWin.hpp"
#else
    #include "SSVUtils/Core/ConsoleFmt/Internal/ConsoleFmtImplNull.hpp"
#endif
```

---

**Error:**

> error: #elif with no expression:
>
> #elif SSVU_OS_WINDOWS

Is my code invalid or is there a bug in MinGW? I think I'm using `#elif` correctly.

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote?

Comment: `#ifdef X` is the same as `#if defined(X)`, not as `#if X`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safe solution, IMO, is to define `SSVU_OS_*` in such a way that it doesn't matter whether you use `#if` or `#ifdef`.

```
#if (__linux || __unix || __posix)
    #define SSVU_OS_LINUX 1
#elif (_WIN64 || _WIN32)
    #define SSVU_OS_WINDOWS 1
#else
    #define SSVU_OS_UNKNOWN 1
#endif
```

This lets your `#ifdef`/`#elif` work already as it is. For consistency, you can then clean that up to

```
#if SSVU_OS_LINUX
    #include "SSVUtils/Core/ConsoleFmt/Internal/ConsoleFmtImplUnix.hpp"
#elif SSVU_OS_WINDOWS
    #include "SSVUtils/Core/ConsoleFmt/Internal/ConsoleFmtImplWin.hpp"
#else
    #include "SSVUtils/Core/ConsoleFmt/Internal/ConsoleFmtImplNull.hpp"
#endif
```

but it isn't strictly necessary.

Making sure your macros work without needing `#ifdef`/`defined` checks allows for simpler expressions if you combine multiple checks (like you already do with the macros of others: you check multiple using `||`).

Answer (score 11):

`#elif` is a contraction of `#else` and `#if`, not `#else` and `#ifdef`, so your line should read:

```
#elif defined(SSVU_OS_WINDOWS)
```

Edit: Because undefined macros expand to `0` in `#if` expressions, you could also use the original variant and define the active macro with a value of `1`. (As hvd has just posted and explained.)

Comment: Also, `defined` is not a function. The parentheses are not needed.

Comment: ...but don't hurt either. I like them, same as with `sizeof`. ;)

Answer (score 4):

To explain why it works in Linux but fails in Windows:

```
#elif (_WIN64 || _WIN32)
```

If `_WIN64` has been defined then it gets replaced, e.g. if these had been defined

```
#define _WIN64
#define _WIN32
```

then the first line expands to

```
#elif ( || )
```

which would generate an error. However, if those tokens were not defined at all, they get replaced by `0`:

```
#elif (0 || 0)
```

which is OK.